# How to pass a View to a queryRun?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, rdp, dynamics-ax-2012

I like to pass to "QueryRun" a View. if I put this line I have error in visual studio :

```
ProjPostTransView = queryRun.get(tablenum(ProjPostTransView));
```

but if I put this line I don't have any error :

```
custTable = qeuryRun.get(tablenum(CustTable));
```

this last line don't generate error because I feel "table" to "queryrun". and now I need to past a "View" not table.

Comment: the error is not good type for function !

queryRun.get(x); => type of x must be TableId (tableid is an EDT) if i put tablenum(custtable) im sure i will return an table id. but tablenum(custtableView) don't return an tableId

Comment: Passing a view to the `tablenum` function does return an `int`. I think @JanB.Kjeldsen is right, the problem may be that the view does not exist in the query.

Comment: my query contain only one think and that is the view

Answer (score 2):

Well, the table or view you want to `get` must be one of tables or views that is defined on the  "static" query: `queryRun.query()`.

```
queryRun = new QueryRun(queryStr(CustTableQuery));
```

Here it would be unreasonable to expect the queryRun to `get` anything but `CustTable`.

To see the SQL (including the `FROM` tables) use:

```
info(queryRun.query().dataSourceNo(1).toString());
```

Comment: static void QueryRun_View(Args _args)
    {
        QueryRun queryRun;
    
    
        queryRun = new QueryRun(queryStr(ProjTransQuery));
    
        while(queryRun.next())
        {
    info(strFmt("%1",queryRun.query().dataSourceNo(1)));//.toString());//     dateSourceNo(1).toString());
    }
    
}

i try to do it in a JOP but in the execution it generate error : wrong type argument

Comment: You can copy/paste now: dataSourceNo was misspelled dateSourceNo.

Comment: yes I saw it and I corrected .. you can see the code of the job I had in the pit words comment

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get `ProjPostTransView` view from `ProjTransQuery`, that will not work. `ProjPostTransView` is not a data source on that query. It is a Dependent Object. This means that the view references the query. Not the other way around. (Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb278121(v=ax.50).aspx)

Comment: OMG :(((( ProjTransQuery is composed from union of different other view.. and in my SSRSreport i need different methode implemented in those view ! so now i must make an other query composed from table and not view.. i can not do else !!! :'(

Comment: It would be helpful if you would tell us exactly from what query you are trying to get the view. The problem is NOT that it is a view instead of a table.

Answer (score 0):

this one work very well but its not what i need

[image: this one work very well but its not what i need]

if i work with table and not view i will make this code for exemple :

[image: if i work with table and not view i will make this code for exemple]

Comment: You do not get it, try to read my answer again, slowly, or read SShaheen's answer.